# FEA using abaqus, and it does not follow the trend

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

I am doing finite element analysis of a donut shape for my school work.

[image]

I'm increasing the thickness of the object with a 1 mm increment and run FEA each time, and then comparing the maximum displacement of the object. According to the mathematical relationship between the stiffness and thickness of this object ($k = 4Ebh^3/L^3$, where $h$ is the thickness), I should be getting a $k$ that increases with the cube of the thickness. Although it roughly follows the trend, it doesn't match the mathematical model perfectly... why is that? Is anything happening in that donut shape that I haven't caught, like buckling? And how would that affect the displacement or stiffness? 
[image: displacement vs thickness]

[image: displacement vs height]

Comment: How isn't it matching the mathematical model? Is the deflection greater or lesser than what you expected? And is that consistent or is it sometimes greater and sometimes lesser than the mathematical result?

Comment: @Wasabi, the deflection decreases as the thickness increases (which means the stiffness increases), which is expected result. However, it doesn't follow the trend of h^3 term... the stiffness should be cubed as much as the increase in the thickness... any thoughts?

Comment: You say it "doesn't follow the trend". I understand that. What I don't understand is ***in which way*** is it not following that trend? Is the stiffness increasing (or deflection decreasing) more than you were expecting? When you double the thickness, the deflection should mathematically drop by a factor of 8 ($2^3$). Is it actually dropping by a factor of 9? Or of 6?

Comment: What type of elements are you using? If you are using solid elements and automatic mesh generation, each mesh will be different and the errors caused by the finite size of the elements will be different. That might explain why your results follow the trend "roughly" but not "exactly." Try running one geometry with different meshes, and see how much the results change.

Comment: @Wasabi sorry, I should've asked more clearly. so yes, it follows the trend roughly, not "exactly", but my research professor told me that it should actually follow exactly... for example, lets say the displacement of 1mm thickness model was 20mm, and when i increase the thickness to 2mm, i should get about 5mm, but instead i get 17mm. does it make it clear? he said it might have something to do with the geometry

Comment: @alephzero thanks! I used square mesh, and i made as many mesh as I possibly could, to make more accurate result. would the square mesh might be causing this problem? if I were to change, what would be a good option? I tried using the triangle mesh, but it wasn't working for my model.

Comment: Ah, well, I would not categorize that as "roughly" following the expected trend, since that's a HUGE error (doubling should lead to an eight-fold drop from 20mm to 2.5mm, so dropping just to 17 is a massive error). This question is really hard to answer without exploring the model itself, so either [edit] your question to add A LOT more information (basically enough for someone to replicate your results exactly), or ask a Teaching Assistant for help at your university.

Comment: @Wasabi I've made a plot with the results I got from the abaqus. Please take a look at the plots I've just edited in. does it ring a bell at all?

Comment: I take it "height" is actually the width of the ring, which should indeed have a linear behavior. Yours isn't very linear, but whatever. The big problem is with the thickness diagram, which isn't cubic at all. It goes from around 17mm with 1mm thickness  to basically 0mm at 2mm, when it should actually show around 2mm deflection. So I can tell you there's something wrong with your model, but I can't say exactly what. Again, we'll need all the data on how you built your model so we can replicate things on our side. Though I do think this would be easier with a Teaching Assistant.

Comment: I would take a guess that the problem is how the different models are constrained and/or how the loads are applied, but I agree with @Wasabi these results look completely wrong to me, not "nearly following a trend".

Comment: Are these shell elements? or brick (continuum) elements?  If the later, my guess is you don't have enough elements through the thickness.  You'll probably need at least 7 through the thickness to get a good result.  Shell elements will give better results without requiring as many elements.

Comment: @DanielKiracofe That depends on the solid element. For naïve element formulations you are correct, but ways to fix that problem have been known for at least 20 years.

Comment: @DanielKiracofe Thanks Daniel, how did you come up with the number 7? is this by convention?

Comment: That was a rule of thumb I was taught in grad school.  As alephzero mentioned, there may be alternatives that can work with fewer elements through the thickness, but it may depend on what element type you use (which you did not specify in your post).  A more general answer would be to always do a convergence study.  i.e. increase the mesh density (e.g. double number of elements through the thickness).  If the results changed (by more than say 1%), then you need more elements.  Keep increasing number of elements until you can add more elements and get the same answer.

Comment: With your displacement approaching zero, try to plot both axes with logarithmic scales. Any power law appears as a straight line on double-logarithmic plots, with the exponent affecting the slope. This may give you more insight if your model works for e.g. thicker rings.

Comment: Could you clarify the loading applied to the ring shape? The diameter used as well. 
Also, the first plot shows a deflection of 16 m. This is usually a sign of something wonky going on.
Do you have any non-linear options turned on?